# Examples/HowTos for CE-HTML?

Tags: xhtml, television

I searched for examples or HowToes for CE-HTML. It took me 1/2 day and I found nearly nothing. I thought it would be a open standard like html which can be used by everyone. But it seems to cost 450$ only to see the [standard](http://www.ce.org/Standards/browseByCommittee_2757.asp).

Is there a good source to get more information? Ebooks? Blogs? Forum?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can register on [www.yourappontv.com](http://www.yourappontv.com) as a Philips partner and there are some examples and pieces of documentaion.